# ActiveDirectory C# - get all Members in Group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm trying to build a method to get all Members in a given Group from my Active Directory.

If I run the following Code, which seems to be fine (I think), I just get one User but not all.

That's my method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetNestedGroupName("Groupname");
        }

       public static void GetNestedGroupName(string groupName)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ad.domain.com"))
            {
             using (GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName))
            {
                if (group != null)
                {
                    foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("name: " + p.SamAccountName);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `build a method wich returns me all Members` that above doesn't return anything. It also closes because nothing is stopping the console from staying open. Add a `Console.ReadLine();` after the `GetNestedGroupName("Groupname");`.

Comment: Hi, youre so right, Ive updated my Code but the console isnt staying open.

Comment: It's because you're throwing an exception, so it closes out.

Comment: Hi, Ive added a new Version, but now I get just one user and not all.

Comment: So are you able to run the code, like you mentioned but yet you get an error? If you step through in debug mode, where does the error get thrown? I've the same thing but didn't use the second using statement.  `GroupPrincipal searchGroup= new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
                searchGroup.Name = "<SearchCriteria*"; // I used a wildcard in my search`

Comment: IVe updated my text sorry was missing that, Im getting now only one User but there more in my group.

Comment: @CodeCase See my answer below. It looks like you only get one user because you stop the loop with the `ReadLine()` and you need to manually hit enter for each iteration. You should remove that line. My code below handles that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you all the members in the group. I've written another block that helps me find group names but I don't see any use for that second using you have on the `GroupPrincipal` - I generally output this to a text file.

```
      using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting Members");
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "<GROUP NAME>");
                foreach (Principal p in group.Members)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
                   Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
             }
```